# Simple groups and irreducible characters of degree 3

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

The only simple finite groups admitting an irreducible character of degree 3 are $\mathfrak{A}_5$ and $PSL(2,7)$. That seems to be a result coming from Blichfelt's work on $GL(3,\mathbb{C})$, which I cannot find. Is there a proof available somewhere ?